# Sort numpy array in-place using order from a second array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Let two ndarrays: `A` of shape `(n, *m)`, and `B` of shape `(n, )`. Is there a way to sort `A` **in-place** using the order that would sort `B`?

Sorting `A` with `B` is easy using [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html), but this is not done in-place:

```
A = A[np.argsort(B)]
```

---

**Comments:**

- `A` and `B` have different dtypes, and `A` can have more than two dimensions. Hence they can’t be stacked to use `ndarray.sort()`.
- `A` takes up a lot of space, which is why it needs to be sorted in-place. Any solution requiring twice the space occupied by `A` would therefore defeat this purpose.
- The title of this question “[Re-arranging numpy array in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26257067/re-arranging-numpy-array-in-place)” may sound related, but the question itself is not very clear, and the answers do not match my question.

Comment: Looks like this is just an advanced indexing task, `A[arr,:]`, indexing the rows of `A`.  That necessarily is a copy.  Even if you use `A[:] = ...` to write the new values back 'on-to' `A`, there will be a temporary buffer with the data.

Comment: @hpaulj: indeed, I was wondering if there is a way to do this without indexing and hence without creating such a buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that works by following cycles in the index array. It can optionally be compiled using pythran giving a significant speedup if rows are small (80x for 10 elements) and a small speedup if rows are large (30% for 1000 elements).

To keep it pythran compatible I had to simplify it a bit, so it only accepts 2D arrays and it only sorts along axis 0.

Code:

```
import numpy as np

#pythran export take_inplace(float[:, :] or int[:, :], int[:])

def take_inplace(a, idx):
    n, m = a.shape
    been_there = np.zeros(n, bool)
    keep = np.empty(m, a.dtype)
    for i in range(n):
        if been_there[i]:
            continue
        keep[:] = a[i]
        been_there[i] = True
        j = i
        k = idx[i]
        while not been_there[k]:
            a[j] = a[k]
            been_there[k] = True
            j = k
            k = idx[k]
        a[j] = keep
```

Sample run using compiled version. As indicated above compilation is only required for small rows, for larger rows pure python should be fast enough.

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import take_inplace
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.random((1000, 10))
>>> idx = a[:, 4].argsort()
>>>
>>> take_inplace.take_inplace(a, idx)
>>>
# correct
>>> np.all(np.arange(1000) == a[:, 4].argsort())
True
>>>
# speed
>>> timeit(lambda: take_inplace.take_inplace(a, idx), number=1000)
0.011950935004279017
>>>
# for comparison
>>> timeit(lambda: a[idx], number=1000)
0.02985276997787878
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot!
I replaced the 1st line of `take_inplace` by `n, *m = a.shape` so that `a` could have 2 or more dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can set `A` beforehand as a *structured array* whose datatype is composed of a subarray of shape `(m, )` and a scalar of the same type (e.g., `np.int32`), then you can sort it in-place with respect to `B`. For example:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.array([3, 1, 2])
A = np.array([[10, 11], [20, 21], [30, 31]])

(n, m) = A.shape

dt = np.dtype([('a', np.int32, (m, )), ('b', int)])
A2 = np.array([(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)], dtype=dt)

A2.sort(order='b')
print A2
```